# PrimeNg with Angular 7. Mistake with @angular/animation

Tags: angular, primeng

Have a problem with primeng in app.module.ts. When I add to imports I have mistake below

http://prntscr.com/oz0l6v

my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform- 
browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TreePrimeComponent } from './tree-prime/tree-prime.component';


import { AutoCompleteModule } from 'primeng/autocomplete'; // - primeNG
import { DropdownModule } from 'primeng/dropdown'; // - primeNG

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     AppComponent,
     TreePrimeComponent
     ],
 imports: [
  BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule, 
FormsModule, 
ReactiveFormsModule,
AutoCompleteModule,
DropdownModule 
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

[image]

I delete @angular/animation and primeng and install them old version. Nut it doesn't help/ Where is a problem?

Comment: did `npm install` already?

Comment: Why am I not seeing `primeng` in your dependencies?